# Configure squid to handle relative urls

Tags: linux, http, networking, proxy, squid

I built and installed squid [3.5.23](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/) as follows:

- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid
- make all
- make install

[Here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#Squid-3.5_default_config) is the default squid.conf used by the version. I made minimal modifications to to the file to make my setup anonymous:

```
forwarded_for delete
request_header_access Via deny all
request_header_access Cache-Control deny all
```

After I got the (remote) proxy server running, I confirmed that I could configure my (local) browser to send traffic through it. I then took it to the next step, and had my router send all traffic originating from my local network to my proxy server:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.11.0/24 -d ! 192.168.11.0/24 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 100.200.30.40:3128
```

However, all of my requests came back with a 400 from squid (BAD REQUEST). On investigating further, I discovered that the request headers were using relative urls (my browser is smart enough to always use absolute urls if it knows it is talking to a proxy server).

I know HTTP 1.1 headers are required to have a `Host` header, which squid can use to determine the original destination of packets it receives. How do I configure the proxy server to use that header? I am looking for the squid 3.5 equivalent of [httpd_accel_uses_host_header on](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Squid.+The+definitive+guide/Appendix+A.+Config+File+Reference/httpd_accel_uses_host_header/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running squid in [accelerator mode](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/cfgman/http_port.html) fixed this:

```
http_port 3128 accel
```